# Using IF and WHERE ANY in Query() function

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, filter, google-query-language, nested-if

I have the following query function that displays data based on the selection of two dropdown cells:

`=QUERY('Rates Master'!A1:G,"SELECT * WHERE YEAR(A) = "&B1&" AND F = '"&B2&"'",1)`

Cell **B1** consists of:

```
Any
2019
2020
2021
```

I would like to modify my query that:

**If "Any" is selected, entries with any date are displayed.**

I'm completely stumped though - would greatly appreciate any guidance on how to formulate this correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add switch:

```
=QUERY('Rates Master'!A1:G,
 "where 1=1"& 
  IF(B1="",, " and YEAR(A) = "&B1&")& 
  IF(B2="",, " and F = '"&B2&"'"), 1)
```